# Got "Unknown plugin name: aws:createImage" while creating SSM Document

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, amazon-systems-manager

I would like to create an SSM document for scheduling weekly backup AMI images, I have tried to copy the content from the built-in AWS-CreateImage document and made a few quick modifications to meet my requirements, but I couldn't pass the examination and keep getting this error message:

> InvalidDocumentContent: Unknown plugin name: aws:createImage

Here is the content of my customized document:

```
{
  "description": "Creates an AMI image from an EC2 instance",
  "schemaVersion": "2.2",
  "assumeRole": "{{ AutomationAssumeRole }}",
  "parameters": {
    "InstanceId": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Required) The ID of the Amazon EC2 instance."
    },
    "NoReboot": {
      "type": "Boolean",
      "description": "(Optional) Do not reboot the instance before creating the image.",
      "default": true
    },
    "AutomationAssumeRole": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Optional) The ARN of the role that allows Automation to perform the actions on your behalf. ",
      "default": ""
    }
  },
  "mainSteps": [
    {
      "name": "createImage",
      "action": "aws:createImage",
      "onFailure": "Abort",
      "inputs": {
        "InstanceId": "{{ InstanceId }}",
        "ImageName": "VoIP-Weekly-Backup-AMI-{{ 'now' | date('YYYYMMdd-HHmmss') }}",
        "NoReboot": "{{ NoReboot }}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    "createImage.ImageId"
  ]
}
```

I have checked the [official documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-create.html) about actions, and it looks like `aws:createImage` indeed exists, so I wonder what is wrong with my settings or syntax? What am I missing? What can I do to fix this issue? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Try with `schemaVersion` '0.3.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the idea, I noticed that the built-in document use `schemaVersion 0.3` generally, but it just doesn't work for me, got this error message "InvalidDocumentSchemaVersion: 0.3 is not a valid schema version for Command document type".

Comment: @Marcin It worked if I change the document type from `Command` to `Automation`, meaning `schemaVersion 0.3` works perfectly for document type `Automation`.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I will make answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use [Schema version 0.3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/documents-schemas-features.html#automation-doc-syntax-examples) instead of newer `2.2`. It seems that new schema does not support all actions.

Comment: I am also wondering if there is any table showing the mapping of actions and schema version.

Comment: @Corey Couldn't find one. AWS docs, in general, are far from perfect.